# Is there a way to add furniture to Minecraft SMP?

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition

I've already investigated the mod [FancyPack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=163224), and it is only for single-player. Is there any way to add furniture to Minecraft SMP?

Just to make it clear, as I'm being pinged once a month by someone who hasn't understood the question or read the existing "answers":

- Yes, **everyone on the server would have to install the mod**. I realize that this is the case and have no problem with it. I'm not looking for a work-around of this.
- No, **faking furniture with existing blocks does not count**. I'm asking for a furniture mod, i.e. a mod that would add furniture into the game.

Comment: Any mod that adds new content (pistons, creatures, furniture, etc) would require both a server mod and client mod to work on SMP. It would also require everyone connecting to that server to have the mod installed.

Comment: @Macha: Sure, I'd be fine with that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we've ruled game-rec's to be off-topic.

Comment: @badp whats a game-rec, and why is it off topic? i want to ask a question about a possible minecraft mod but it seems some mod related questions are closed and some are not. I cant seem to find a pattern.

Comment: I think @badp was just in a bad mood.

Comment: Your original question was off-topic, since it's just a game-rec of  a different colour. I have edited your question to make it on topic though, by turning it into a problem to be solved (which could be solved through someone sharing a mod)

Comment: @Wipqozn: Thanks for fixing the question. Semantics seems like a weird reason to close a question instead of editing it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can add furniture with Furniture 1.1.0 found [here](http://www.minecraftmine.org/furniture-mod/).

Comment: You still have to get everyone to get the mod

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get this working in SMP as soon as I have the time.

Answer (score -2):

Yeas, you can try [fancypack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=163224).

Comment: Fancypack is not for multiplayer.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, there is no way for a server to add blocks, only single player mods are capable of adding blocks in that way. Theoretically, if both the server and the client had the mod (and the mod was designed correctly,) they would agree on the existence of a non-standard block. However, to my knowledge, nobody has accomplished this, though that may change with official mod support which, (fingers crossed) would allow client and server mods to work in concert, and allow clients to download the mod from any server they would join.

Comment: [Really?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brGhO6ZfBjo)

Comment: The Yogscast would be so much worse if they didn't have the lovely British accents.

Answer (score -2):

Macha has already stated that you cannot add any mod for furniture to a server without everyone having that mod.

In the most popular case, you won't know the people on the server. If you do know them, however, convincing them to get a mod would not be that hard.

Until then, settling with wooden stairs and signs on the ends of them may be your best option. I dont think anything else will work.

Comment: "convincing them to get a mod would not be that hard." I'm asking _which_ mod would accomplish this.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I believed that you knew a md you wanted but couldn't get it onto the server. I don't know a mod at this point, but once you find them my answer ^  will be helpful. Sorry I couldn't help you too much.

Answer (score -2):

Unless everyone on a server has the mod you cant add furniture to the server (that functions as intended) but you can make aesthetic furniture such as those in this video:

Comment: I'm looking for a mod that adds real furniture. As the question and comments to the question state, there's no problem with having everyone on the server use the mod.

Comment: A real furniture mod would be less limited (shapes, block sizes, textures, ...) than faking furniture, and would be used for its intended purpose.